# CLOUD9 - KMS: The AWS Access Key Id needs a subscription for the service

Tags: aws-cloud9

when trying to set up cloud9 I get the this error "KMS: The AWS Access Key Id needs a subscription for the service"

I have enabled all the cloud9 permissions for this user, as well as the KMS super user.